# Difference between [[n]] and $`n` in R lists?

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have two slightly different nested lists and I'm not sure about the difference and how to convert one to the other.

One list is structured as `[[30][[5]][10]` while the other is like:

```
[[30]]$`5`[10]
```

The data is the exact same (numeric):

```
[[30]]$`5`
 [1] -0.58924399  0.50338044 -0.66033344 -0.81774557 -1.30100686  0.57346537
 [7] -0.09911783  0.14725195  0.02574962 -0.97657000
```

vs.

```
[[30]][[5]]
 [1] -0.58924399  0.50338044 -0.66033344 -0.81774557 -1.30100686  0.57346537
 [7] -0.09911783  0.14725195  0.02574962 -0.97657000
```

I got the `$` type by using a `split` function on 2x2 matrices:

```
foreach(x = matr, .export = "asset") %dopar% {
    i <- i + 1
    return(split(matr[[i]], rep(1:ncol(matr[[i]]), each = nrow(matr[[i]]))))
  }
```

The `[[]]` was generated manually using nested lapply functions:

```
lst <- lapply(1:30, function(x) lapply(1:5, function(y) rnorm(10)))
```

How can I convert from the `$` type to the `[[]]` type? What is the difference?

**Edit**

It appears that using `$` instead of `[[]]` is somehow affecting my parallel execution of lapply.

Comment: That is the name of the list elements. try `names(mylist) <- NULL`

Comment: It appears that the names are already set to NULL on both lists.

Comment: They aren't. Try this `a=1:4;b=rep(1:2,2);split(a,b)`. the function will generate names automatically. Next try this and compare the results `x=split(a,b);names(x)=NULL;x`

Comment: You might want to read [this explanation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators). HTH